# Apply CSS to all browsers except IE using media query

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I found a way to apply media queries to IE using:

```
@media (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

}
```

Is there a way do the same to apply CSS to all browsers but IE? Something like:

```
@media not( (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) ) {

}
```

I'd like to avoid using the HTML tags.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use a [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) query for browsers that are not Internet Explorer. `@supports` queries are [compatible with all browsers except Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#Browser_compatibility).

```
@supports not (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   /* Non-IE styles here */
}
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/layzee/full/vQLpqO/)

Comment: ok now im confused. i thought that code will run css if browser is Edge, since it says there "Non-IE". But i tried that in the edge browser and it does not work. Chrome and Firefox works.

Comment: I must have misunderstood your comment. Did you try the Codepen example? I tried it in `Edge 44/EdgeHTML 18` on Windows 10 and this is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/0vYnhWm